# Usar Procedimiento Almacenado en Laravel

Tags: laravel

buen día.

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado de send_email de SQL Server de la siguiente manera

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'XXXXX',  
@recipients = 'XXX@XXX.XXX.XXx',  
@body = 'correo electrónico de prueba .',  
@subject = 'PRUEBA' ;
```

como puedo aplicarlo en mi controlador para enviar el correo

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
$queryResult = DB::select('EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail');
```

Para integrar parametros intentalo asi:

```
$queryResult = DB::select('EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ?, ?, ?, ?', ['XXXXX', 'XXX@XXX.XXX.XXx', 'correo electrónico de prueba .', 'PRUEBA']);
```

Comment: Amigo, pero para los parametros?

Comment: Intentalo asi: 
$queryResult = DB::select('EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ?, ?, ?, ?', ['XXXXX', 'XXX@XXX.XXX.XXx', 'correo electrónico de prueba .', 'PRUEBA']);

Comment: En tu caso seria poner entre parentesis los params.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca tanto el código del comentario, como su explicación en cuanto al funcionamiento del mismo. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ Lee [answer].